# Swift: High performance String transformation?

Tags: swift, string, nsstring

I have around 36000 files containing around 250 word each, and I need to transform each word by removing every decimal characters, and lowercasing any uppercase characters.

I pass each word I read in a function that returns the modified word in 
order for me to index it later.

The issue is that with this huge amount of characters, it's super slow.

I have been trying to iterate on my strings, manipulate `Characters` like in C, play with ascii values, but Swift is kind of terrible for this, requiring to reconstruct Strings from Characters all the time.

I came with this little piece of code, but my knowledge in Swift for this precise topic is to broad to find better. Also, I'm using Swift 4.2.

```
func processToken(token: String) -> String {
    var result = String()

    for ascii in token.utf8 {
        if ascii > 64 && ascii < 91 {
            result.append(String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(ascii + 32))))
        }
        else if ascii > 96 && ascii < 123 {
            result.append(String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(ascii))))
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: If you want the best performance, you could write the critical part in C/Objective-C.

Comment: @cristik Thats actually a very bad advice. Swift is not slower than C. Its not about languages, its about algorithms.

Comment: @Sulthan there are 36000 files, this means 36k times of boilerplate Swift code that wraps a `char*`. Please don't try to convince me this is not slower than C.

Comment: Swift `String` is not good at manipulating UTF-8 byte sequence, as its internal representation is based on UTF-16. So, if you change `.utf8` to `.utf16` (some parts need to be modified according to the change), the performance would be improved, a little. If you want a critical performance, you should better read the file as `Data` and manipulate it through pointers. Swift pointers are as fast as C.

Comment: @Cristik You don't have to use `String` in Swift, you can manipulate raw bytes the same way as in C. As I say, it's not about languages, it's about the things you use.  Also note that if the OP really needs to use UTF8 then it won't be so easy without `String`. In my opinion opening and closing 36 000 files should be the performance problem here anyway, not the transformation.

Comment: @Sulthan this is what I thought too but the whole opening/reading/closing barely represents 20% of the whole running time

Comment: @Sulthan so what algorithm would solve the file opening/closing issue? :)

Comment: Also all this code is running in the GCD async... Don't know if that change anything

Comment: Some more information would be helpful: What do you consider a “decimal character” – Only 0..9, or decimal characters from non-latin alphabets as well? Why do you separate the text into words (and how)? Your code only considers a-z and A-Z, what about letters from other languages/alphabets? What should happen to the remaining characters (spaces, punctuation, emojis, ...)?

Comment: A decimal character as simply 0..9. I only care about latin characters, and yes there is also other operations I need to do, but in order to keep this post simple, I am only trying to optimize this small part

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution that should be pretty fast. It's an Objective-C function that mostly uses plain old C. Why C? Because we know for sure what the C-runtime does which is basically providing an ultra-thin wrapper around memory. On the other hand many of the lower-level details of what the Swift-runtime does are unknown and for good reasons. However, it can be safely assumed that Swift comes with a higher performance overhead than plain C. The only way to beat C in this regard is to go all the way down to assembler or to open up a hex editor of your choice and type in the op codes and the operands yourself. Don't get me wrong, Swift should always be preferred for a ton of reasons, but if performance is crucial then Objective-C / C is the tool of choice.

So here comes the code snippet. It takes an NSString and gets rid of all the digits and converts all upper-case characters to their lower-case counterparts.

```
-  ( NSString* ) convert:( NSString* ) source
{
    const char bitmaskNonAsciiChar =  ( char ) ( 1 << 7 );
    const char* cSource = [ source UTF8String ];
    size_t strLength = strlen( cSource );
    size_t bufferSize = sizeof( char ) * strLength + 1;

    char *result = ( char* ) malloc( bufferSize );
    memset( result, '\0', bufferSize );

    int currentIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < strLength; ++i )
    {
        // Check if this is an UTF-8 character that's longer than one byte. If so, it can't be an ASCII character and we can just write this character to the result buffer.
        if( ( cSource[ i ] & bitmaskNonAsciiChar ) == bitmaskNonAsciiChar )
        {
            result[ currentIndex++ ] = cSource[ i ];
            continue;
        }

        // Now we know it is an ASCII character, so we need to check for digits and upper-case characters.
        if( cSource[ i ] >= ( char ) 46 && cSource[ i ] <= ( char ) 57 )
        {
            continue;
        }

        if( cSource[ i ] >= ( char ) 65 && cSource[ i ] <= ( char ) 90 )
        {
            result[ currentIndex++ ] = cSource[ i ] + ( char ) 32;
            continue;
        }

        // It's an ASCII character that is neither a digit nor upper-cased, so we just write it to the result buffer.
        result[ currentIndex++ ] = cSource[ i ];
    }

    NSString *resultString = [ NSString stringWithUTF8String: result ];
    free( result );

    return resultString;
}
```

Here is a slightly modified version which can be used if you know for sure that the input size is rather small. This version doesn't create the result buffer on the heap using malloc, but simply uses stack memory instead. If you want to run this on a word-by-word basis, then having all those memory allocations for every call is a massive waste of time. If however you intend to run this on a file-by-file basis and you don't know how large the files can possibly get, then the first version might be better.

```
-  ( NSString* ) convert:( NSString* ) source
{
    const char bitmaskNonAsciiChar =  ( char ) ( 1 << 7 );
    const char* cSource = [ source UTF8String ];
    size_t strLength = strlen( cSource );
    size_t bufferSize = sizeof( char ) * strLength + 1;

    char result[ bufferSize ];
    memset( result, '\0', bufferSize );

    int currentIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < strLength; ++i )
    {
        // Check if this is an UTF-8 character that's longer than one byte. If so, it can't be an ASCII character and we can just write this character to the result buffer.
        if( ( cSource[ i ] & bitmaskNonAsciiChar ) == bitmaskNonAsciiChar )
        {
            result[ currentIndex++ ] = cSource[ i ];
            continue;
        }

        // Now we know it is an ASCII character, so we need to check for digits and upper-case characters.
        if( cSource[ i ] >= ( char ) 46 && cSource[ i ] <= ( char ) 57 )
        {
            continue;
        }

        if( cSource[ i ] >= ( char ) 65 && cSource[ i ] <= ( char ) 90 )
        {
            result[ currentIndex++ ] = cSource[ i ] + ( char ) 32;
            continue;
        }

        // It's an ASCII character that is neither a digit nor upper-cased, so we just write it to the result buffer.
        result[ currentIndex++ ] = cSource[ i ];
    }

    NSString *resultString = [ NSString stringWithUTF8String: result ];

    return resultString;
}
```